# Weak convergence implying a somewhat stronger form of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

$\renewcommand{\Re}{\mathbb{R}}$Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $\Gamma\subset X^*$ be a collection of continuous linear functions $f:X\to \Re$.

Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence in $X$ so that:

$$
f(x_k)\to 0,\ \text{for all } f \in \Gamma\tag{1}.
$$

We may say that $(x_n)_n$ is $\Gamma$-weakly convergent to $0$.

I wonder under what conditions we may let $f$ meander in $\Gamma$ as follows:

$$
f_n(x_n)\to 0,\ \text{for all } (f_n)_n \subset \Gamma\tag{2}.
$$

In general (1) does not imply (2) and my question is under what assumptions on $\Gamma$ it does.

Condition (2) is reminiscent of [continuous convergence](http://planetmath.org/continuousconvergence).

I tried to show that if $\Gamma$ is compact or equicontinuous, then (1) implies (2), but to no avail.

*Update:* Let $\Gamma=\{f_1,\ldots, f_p\}$ be finite. Then $y_k \triangleq (f_1(x_k), \ldots, f_p(x_k))\to 0$. Let $(b_k)_k$ be a bounded sequence of $p$-vectors with $\|b_k\|\leq M$. Then $|b_k'y_k|\leq M \|y_k\| \to 0$. Therefore, $\sum_{i=1}^p b_{k,i}f_i(x_k)\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$. We may then say that if (1) holds with $\Gamma' = \{\sum_{i=1}^p b_i f_i; (b_1,\ldots, b_p)\in A\}$, where $A$ is bounded convex, then (1) implies (2).

Comment: We may not say that $(x_n)$ is weakly convergent to zero, because we have no information on $\Gamma$. For all we know, it may contain only the zero functional.

Comment: @uniquesolution Yes, it indeed does not converge in the weak topology to $0$, but in that topology induced by $\Gamma\subset X^*$. I defined it so to be able to refer to it. If $\Gamma=\{0\}$, or if it is a singleton in general, (1) implies (2) trivially.

Comment: Oh, OK, $\Gamma$-weakly convergent. That's not very interesting. If it would have been, I would have heard about it by now.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis why (1) does not imply (2)? take a sequence $f_m \in \Gamma$  and for every $m$ you have that $f_m(x_n) \rightarrow 0$ as $n$ goes to infinity

Comment: @MariosGretsas For fixed $m$, indeed, $(f_m(x_n))_n$ converges. Condition (2) requires that $(f_n(x_n))_n$ converges to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: The following is not a solution of the problem as stated but to the similar question if one replaces *sequences* by *nets*.

I interpret the question that you want the equivalence of (1) and (2) for all sequences $(x_n)_n$ in $X$. This holds if and only if $\Gamma$ is contained and bounded in some finite dimensional subspace of $X^*$ (boundedness with respect to any norm, e.g. the dual norm): To prove this first note that (2) is equivalent to $\sup\{|f(x_n)|:f\in\Gamma\} \to 0$. The equivalence of (1) and (3) thus says that the weak topology $\sigma(X,\Gamma)$ coincides with the topology induced by the seminorm $p(x)=\sup\{|f(x)|:f\in\Gamma\}$. The polar $\Gamma^\circ$ is the unit ball of this seminorm and hence there is a $0$-neighbourhood $U$ w.r.t $\sigma(X,\Gamma)$ contained in $\Gamma^\circ$. Moreover, there are $f_1,\ldots,f_n\in\Gamma$ and $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\varepsilon\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}^\circ \subseteq U$. The theorem of bipolars thus implies $$\Gamma\subseteq \Gamma^{\circ\circ} \subseteq \varepsilon^{-1}\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}^{\circ\circ}=\varepsilon^{-1}\text{asolutely convex hull}\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$$
(because this last set is compact and hence closed e.g. in $(X^*,\sigma(X,X^*)$).

EDIT. Ooops. There is a problem with the argument: If $(X,\sigma(X,\Gamma))$ and $(X,p)$ have the same null-sequences one cannot conclude that the topologies are equal (because the weak topology isn't metrizable)! The classical example  $X=\ell^1$ with $\Gamma$ the unit ball of the dual $\ell^\infty$ is in plain contradiction to my claim. To have $\sigma(X,\Gamma)$ metrizable (in which case the argument is correct) one would need $\Gamma$ countable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. One clarification: When you take $U$, neighbourhood of $0$, you mean that this is open in $\sigma(X,\Gamma)$? And what you do after is that you take an open set from a basis of $\sigma(X,\Gamma)$, namely $\epsilon\{f_1,\ldots, f_n\}^\circ$, and put it inside $U$?

Comment: It is rather a matter of taste if you write this in terms of $0$-neighbourhoods (i.e., a set $U$ which contains an open set $A\ni 0$) and a basis thereof or in terms of seminorms: The topology $\sigma(X,\Gamma)$ is given by seminorms of the form $q(x)=\max\{|f_1(x)|,\ldots,|f_n(x)|\}$ with $f_1,\ldots,f_n\in \Gamma$.

Comment: Regarding your update: The unit ball of $\ell^\infty$ is not contained in a bounded finite-dimensional set, so it is not a counterexample.

Comment: It is indeed a counterexample to my proposed characterization (which only becomes correct if you replace *sequences* in $X$ by *nets*).

Comment: You stated in the beginning that (1) is equivalent to (2) - or $\sigma(X,\Gamma) = \tau_{p}$ - if and only if $\Gamma$ is contained in a finite-dimensional and bounded set. But, if $\Gamma$ is the ball of $\ell^\infty$ it does not satisfy this requirement - isn't it? We cannot contain it in a finite-dimensional subspace.

Comment: The claim that (1) is equivalent to (2) if and only if $\Gamma$ is contained and bounded in afinite dimesional subspace is wrong. The latter condition only characterizes the coincidence of the topologies but (as the example with $X=\ell^1$ shows) this is not the same as having the same null sequences.

Comment: Is it however correct to say that if $\sigma(X,\Gamma)=\tau_p$, then (1) and (2) are equivalent? (without the converse being true). Indeed, sequences do not characterise the topology, but equality of the topologies implies that that $\sigma(X,\Gamma)$-convergence is the same as $\tau_p$-convergence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63804/discussion-between-pantelis-sopasakis-and-jochen).